# Create new column based on ending of character string in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column `Trial` based on the ending of a character string. For example, the characters that end with the number **2** like `A3-H2` or `A9-H2` will be considered Trial **2** and those not ending with a number like `A3-H` or `A9-H` will be considered Trial 1. This should be an easy `ifelse` statement but I don't know how to do it based on the end of a character string.

It would go from this:

```
      Plant     Trtmt    
1:     SC       A3-H
2:     SC       A3-H2
3:     SC       A9-H
4:     SC       A9-H2
```

To this:

```
      Plant     Trtmt    Trial
1:     SC       A3-H       1
2:     SC       A3-H2      2
3:     SC       A9-H       1
4:     SC       A9-H2      2
```

Real Data:

```
dput(stack.df)
structure(list(Plant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("SC", 
"W"), class = "factor"), Trtmt = c("A3-H", "A3-H", "A3-H", "A3-H", 
"A3-H", "A9-H", "A9-H", "A9-H", "A9-H", "A9-H", "A3-H2", "A3-H2", 
"A3-H2", "A3-H2", "A3-H2", "A9-H2", "A9-H2", "A9-H2", "A9-H2", 
"A9-H2")), .Names = c("Plant", "Trtmt"), row.names = c(6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `ifelse(grepl("2$", stack.df$Trtmt), "Trial 2", "Trial 1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

stack.df <- stack.df %>% 
  mutate(Trial = ifelse(grepl("2$", Trtmt), 2, 1))
```

Comment: Well, just `dplyr` would be fine for `mutate`. I just use `tidyverse` by default since I always seem to end up using > 1 package from it, so less typing :)

Comment: Just preference. If I'm manipulating data frames I always use `dplyr`, again just because I'm sure to end up doing > 1 thing.

Comment: give him a break, @RonakShah `mutate` is dplyr. `%>%` is dplyr. This is his workflow, it works, and is a good one.

Comment: @RonakShah because it's his (and many others') idiom. We're not golfing, we're writing sensible modular code. People choose `dplyr` pipes because they fit with their mental model for how to transform and tidy data.

Comment: Like Dan said: it's my workflow and it works :) so it's how I answer questions. Two years ago I'd have given a base R answer.

Comment: fair enough guys. Style and preference are always subjective, we all have our coding style. I just wanted to be sure that I am not missing something. Moreover, my comment was exactly the same as the answer and hence, the question at first place.

Comment: @RonakShah The question asked for an ifelse call to produce a specific behavior. There are only so many ways to write that call. neil didn't steal your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
stack.df %>% mutate(Trial = ifelse(str_sub(Trtmt,-1)=="2", 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
setDT(stack.df)[, Trial := pmax(as.numeric(str_extract(Trtmt, "\\d+$")), 1, na.rm = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last character with `substr(stack.df$Trtmt,nchar(stack.df$Trtmt)-1,nchar(stack.df$Trtmt))`

Like you said, it's an easy ifelse from there :-)